# How to set ListView using BaseAdapter on click event and how to show only one button at a time?

Tags: android

I created ListView using BaseAdapter. When I click on item 1 it's showing a button, but when I click on item 2 then how to hide the button on item 1?

getView method:

```java
viewHolder.textView.setText("AMOUNT : ₹ " + Double.toString(tList.get(i).amount));
viewHolder.textView4.setText("TRX ID : " + tList.get(i).transactionid);
viewHolder.textView5.setText("VOLUME :" + tList.get(i).volume + "Ltr." + "       FUEL TYPE : " + tList.get(i).product);
viewHolder.textView2.setText("PRICE : ₹ " + Double.toString(tList.get(i).price) + "/Ltr.");
viewHolder.textView3.setText("DATE : " + tList.get(i).transactiondate);
viewHolder.layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
view.setTag(viewHolder);

viewHolder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (viewHolder.layout1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) viewHolder.layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        else if (viewHolder.layout1.getVisibility() == View.GONE) viewHolder.layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Comment: please, share complete `getView` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `layout` is your whole layout item and `btn` your button

In `BaseAdapter` create a new variable

```
private int selectedItem = -1; // -1 means nothing is slected
```

then in `getView`

```
viewHolder.textView.setText("AMOUNT : ₹ " + Double.toString(tList.get(i).amount));
viewHolder.textView4.setText("TRX ID : " + tList.get(i).transactionid);
viewHolder.textView5.setText("VOLUME :" + tList.get(i).volume + "Ltr." + "       FUEL TYPE : " + tList.get(i).product);
viewHolder.textView2.setText("PRICE : ₹ " + Double.toString(tList.get(i).price) + "/Ltr.");
viewHolder.textView3.setText("DATE : " + tList.get(i).transactiondate);

if (selectedItem == i)
    viewHolder.btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
    viewHolder.btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

view.setTag(viewHolder);

viewHolder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        selectedItem = i;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```